# Finding the middle of three numbers

Tags: python, function, python-2.7

I'm looking for alternative or more concise ways to return the middle of three unique values. What I have right now is a function:

```
def middle(x, y, z):
    if x > y and x < z:
        return x
    if y > x and y < z:
        return y
    return z
```

Anything better?

Comment: `return sorted((x,y,z))[1]`

Comment: Your attempt actually returns the _highest_ of the three. If you need to write code like this, consider the "between" forms that Python lets you write: `if y < x < z:`. It's much easier to read, and harder to get wrong. (In this case, there's an even _easier_ answer, so I've just left this as a comment rather than an answer.)

Comment: Sorry, I'm an idiot-edited.

Comment: @jmu303: We're all idiots when it comes to things like that, which is exactly why `x < y < z` is better than `y>x and x<z`—even an idiot like me or you won't get it wrong.

Comment: @abarnert Thanks. I added this suggestion in my answer.

Comment: The function in the question isn't quite right. `middle(2, 3, 1)` gives `1`. Actually both `x > y and x < z` and `x > z and x < y` makes `x` the middle one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
def middle(x, y, z):
    return sorted([x, y, z])[1]
```

This should return the middle number. But if you actually meant maximum number

```
def maximum(x, y, z):
    return max([x, y, z])
```

**Edit:** As suggested by abarnert in the comments section, instead of `y>x and x<z` use `x < y < z`, which is more readable and pythonic.

Answer (score 3):

With Python 3.4, [`statistics.median`](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/statistics.html#statistics.median) is in the standard library:

```
import statistics

def middle(x, y, z):
    return statistics.median((x, y, z))
```

With 3.1-3.3, after you [`pip install stats`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/stats/):

```
import stats

def middle(x, y, z):
    return stats.median((x, y, z))
```

I believe a backport for 2.6-2.7 is in the works, but does not yet exist. (For 2.5 or 3.0, just upgrade already.)

Of course if you had 4 values, you'd have to decide what "middle" means; `median` would use the mean of the two middle values, but you might want something different.

Answer (score 2):

```
def middle(x, y, z):
    return x + y + z - max(x, y, z) - min(x, y, z)
```

Just for the fun of it.

Comment: Clever. But try `middle(1, 2, 1e200)`. :)

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun…

We don't really need to sort all three values; we just need to keep track of the 2 largest as we go through the whole list, right?

In general, this can be useful, so the standard library has a way to do exactly that: the [`heapq.nlargest`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.nlargest) function.

```
def middle(x, y, z):
    return heapq.nlargest(2, (x, y, z))[-1]
```

In practice, a heap is much slower than sorting a list, so unless the list is pretty big (3 is nowhere near big enough) and the number of elements you need to remember pretty small (2/3rds is nowhere near small enough), this will actually slow you down a lot. As a quick test will show:

```
In [66]: %timeit heapq.nlargest(2, [1,2,3])[1]
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.78 us per loop

In [67]: %timeit sorted([1,2,3])[1]
1000000 loops, best of 3: 770 ns per loop
```

So, don't use this here, but keep it in your toolbox for the next time you need the 10 top scores out of 500000.

Answer (score 1):

for fun:

```
def middle(x, y, z):
    if x < y:
        if y < z:
            return y
        elif x < z:
            return z
        else:
            return x
    else:
        if x < z:
            return x
        elif y > z:
            return y
        else:
            return z
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also make some kind of a median function which works not only for 3 values

```
def median(list): 
    list = sorted(list) 
    if len(list) % 2 == 0: 
        n = len(list)//2 
        return (list[n]+list[n-1])/2 
    else: 
        return list[len(l)//2]
```

Comment: Why write a median function when there's one already in the stdlib (3.4) or available on PyPI (earlier)?