# Finding the median without using sort

Tags: python, median

I'm fairly new to programing, and I'm doing a problem in class where we need to have the user read in three numbers, and then sort them to find the median using IF statements. We can't use sort. I'm having a really hard time figuring all this out and could use some help. Here's what I have so far but I really don't know what to do.

```
def main():
    nums = []
    x = eval(input('Enter a number: '))
    while x <= 2:
        nums.append(x)
        x = eval(input('Enter a number: '))

main()
```

Comment: Make a sorting function yourself. By the way, using if statements instead of `sort` looks like a silly idea..

Comment: Aside: `eval()` in your function is unnecessary.

Comment: I know it's silly, but that's the assignment. I have to use IF statements to find the median. But I don't know how to assign the inputted variables so I can check them.

Comment: Figure out which number is the smallest, then figure out which of the other two is second-smallest.

Answer (score 2):

Only three numbers? I asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19922939/finding-the-middle-of-three-numbers) a long time ago. A list isn't really necessary for this, but you may use it if you wish.

```
def main():
    a = input("Enter a number: ")
    b = input("Enter a number: ")
    c = input("Enter a number: ")
    # We need to check which number is the median. With three numbers,
    # it's pretty trivial: Whichever number is greater than one or less
    # than the other.
    if c <= b <= a or a <= b <= c:
        return b
    elif c <= a <= b or b <= a <= c:
        return a
    else: # Only one option left.
        return c
```

Comment: Now would I then write print main(), or just main() in order to display what the median is?

Comment: The program is not right, for example: a=1, b=2, c=3

Comment: @HYRY you were right. Fixed

Comment: @user3230393 the way I have it, `main()` returns a variable. So you'd have to print the result in order to explain anything. You can replace the return statements with print statements if you'd like.

Comment: how about there are two equal number: a=3, b=3, c=1

Comment: I see, well when I type main() and then the numbers the median is triggered. Is there a way I can display the median automatically after the third number is entered?

Comment: @user3230393 replace the return statements with print statements.

Comment: when I do that and run the program it gives me invalid syntax

Comment: @HYRY The median is the *middle* number, so the median of `[1,3,3]` is 3.

Comment: @user3230393 Python 3? `print(a)`

Comment: I did that and it does print the number, but it just automatically prints whatever the last number is. It doesn't grab the middle number.

Comment: @user3230393 Could you explain exactly what your input is and the output? The function is working perfectly for me.

Comment: Let's say I type, 4, 6, and 7, the number that prints out is 7.

Comment: @user3230393 Make sure you've typed the function exactly correctly. It's working for me

Comment: Wait, no I think I fixed the problem

Comment: Do you think you'd be willing to help me with another problem?

Comment: @user3230393 Ask another question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21324172/python-addition-table-using-nested-while-loops'

Answer (score 0):

If you are only dealing with 3 numbers, you easily find the median.

```
a = input("Enter a number: ")
b = input("Enter a number: ")
c = input("Enter a number: ")
x=[a,b,c]
x.remove(min(x))
median=min(x)
```

Comment: OP has to use `if statements` it seems, otherwise `np.median` is even easier.

Comment: I know I could dot his much more easily it seems if I could. But having to use IF statements has me really confused.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
def get_median(a, b, c):
    if a > b:
        if b > c:
            return b
        else:
            if a < c:
                return a
        return c
    else:
        if b < c:
            return b
        else:
            if a > c:
                return a
        return c
```

Result:

```
>>> get_median(1,2,3)
2
>>> get_median(3,2,1)
2
>>> get_median(3,3,1)
3
>>> get_median(3,1,1)
1
>>> get_median(4,6,7)
6
>>> get_median(7,6,4)
6
>>> get_median(7,6,7)
7
>>> get_median(2,2,2)
2
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, use IF statement:

```
from itertools import permutations
def median3(x):
    for a, b, c in permutations(x):
        if a <= b <= c:
            return b
```

Comment: That is one cheesy hack, to use permutations instead of sort. Why not do `while not(x[0] <= x[1] <= x[2]): random.shuffle(x)` and then return `x[1]`?